# how can i find the identity of two columns

Tags: sql

I have a table like these:

```
STATE      code     company   rate 
----------------------------------
TX          SD      1         0.5
TX          SD      2         0.5
TX          SD      3         0.7
TX          SD      4         0.5
..........
```

I need to verify that is the rate same under the same state and same code.

I consider to join the table by itself  and get the rate 1 and rate2 , then can use case when to compare the two columns

Something  like this:

```
CASE WHEN COLUMN1 = COLUMN2 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS MyDesiredResult
```

I do not know does it work? How can I can join the table?

Basically, I need a report to see if the rate is different under the same state and same code.

thanks

Comment: You just have to know which state/code have not all the same values for rate?

Comment: yes, sorry for the confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will show you the offending state/code combinations:

```
select state, code, min(rate) min_rate, max(rate) max_rate
  from myTable
 group by state, code
having min(rate) != max(rate)
```

You can process further to find how many rows each rate have. for example using a CTE, but I left it as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from tbl t1
join tbl t2 using (state, code)
where t1.rate <> t2.rate
and t1.company < t2.company;
```

Each row returned will show a mismatch: if there are no mismatches then there will be now rows returned.  The last line just prevents showing all the results twice.

The above query could return a large number of rows if there is even a single `(state, code)` combination that has more than one `rate`.  In order to just see a summary of the distinct rates where they differ, use this instead:

```
select state, code, rate, count(*)
from tbl
group by state, code
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: thanks. As you said i get a large number. so i will try to use the count.